# AngularJS get factory from different module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Module 1:

```
angular.module('mod1', [])
   .factory('mod1Fac', function(){
        return {
          test: function (){
              return('this is from mod1');
          }
        };
   };
```

Module 2:

```
angular.module('mod2', ['mod1'])
   .controller('mod2Ctrl', function (mod1Fac, $scope){
       $scope.string = mod1Fac.test();
   }
```

What changes to this code do I need to make it so I can access the data from mod1's factory into mod2's controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to inject `$scope`,

```
angular.module('mod2', ['mod1'])
   .controller('mod2Ctrl', function (mod1Fac,$scope){
       $scope.string = mod1Fac.test();
   }
```

here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/BrogJiDfqXQiZCikL6iS?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I didn't have that, but that is not the fix, should this code work? because in my own project, it is very similar but it is saying that mod1 isn't available.

Comment: Oh yes I do...weird how this won't work with my project...thank you for your response and answer.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't understand..what is the code or difference between question code & answer code..

Comment: @PankajParkar previously there was not $scope in his question, now he has added